# ORACLE SQL trigger and SUM()

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table COMMANDE and a table REGROUPE. I have that function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE multiplicateur(a NUMBER, taxes NUMBER, c OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    c := a * taxes ;
END multiplicateur;
/
```

I'm trying to make a trigger using that founction to update a total price with taxes from a command that can contain more than one item. I tried this but it doesn't want to work:

```
create or replace TRIGGER MAJ_PRIX_COMMANDE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON REGROUPE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
resultat NUMBER; 
BEGIN
UPDATE COMMANDE
SET COMMANDE.prixTotal = multiplicateur((CAST((SELECT SUM(prixRegroupe)FROM REGROUPE WHERE REGROUPE.numCommande = :NEW.numCommande)AS NUMBER)),1.15,resultat)

WHERE COMMANDE.numCommande = :NEW.numCommande;
END;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to create a function if you want to use the value in a query.

Comment: You mean, an other than the one i already got? I'm not sure i understand

Comment: @XavierSavage - you currently have a procedure, not a function. You could call the procedure first and then use `resultat` in the update. Is it really worthing having a sepearate procedure/function to do that simple calculation though? And are you sure a trigger is the right mechanism here?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I know it's a simple calculation, but it's for a homework, and i need to use a procedure. But If i put my procedure between the Begin and the Update, it doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm with Alex, I think there are better solutions here. It seems like a poor practice despite it being a homework assignment. I'd recommend virtual columns if you have an 11g or new database. https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I sent this from my iPhone; this code hasn't been tested.

```
create or replace TRIGGER MAJ_PRIX_COMMANDE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON REGROUPE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
 resultat NUMBER; 
 l_groupe NUMBER; --will store sum based on numCommande
BEGIN
 --retrieve sum of prixRegroupe
 SELECT SUM(r.prixRegroupe)
   INTO l_groupe
   FROM regroupe r
  WHERE r.numCommande = :NEW.numCommande;

  --call procedure and pass the sum of priRegroupe
  multiplicateur(l_groupe, 1.15, resultat);

  --use precedures out argument to update commande
 UPDATE COMMANDE c
    SET c.prixTotal = resultat
  WHERE c.numCommande = :NEW.numCommande;
END;
```

This code won't work. It will result in a mutating trigger error. Within a trigger you cannot query or modify the same table that the trigger is based on until after the trigger has completed execution.

ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Your problem right now is that you're querying the regroupe table while the trigger is trying to insert/update the same table. This cannot be accomplished.

You'll need to find a way to get the sum of the prixRegroup column some other way. It's late if I think of anything I'll respond tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! it works, but when i try to insert something in REGROUPE, i get this : "*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table." I don't know why, i only update the Commande Table

Comment: @XavierSavage can you please post the full error message? Also, are you saying that you receive this error only when inserting? The trigger works fine with updates and deletes?

Comment: Wrote it below in an new answer to my question

Comment: @XavierSavage i added comments to my answer. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a better answer. Perhaps someone else can. I know that this is a homework assignment, but in the real world it's considered poor design.